# Accessing Git private repos should fail automatically without asking for creds

Tags: git

I am trying to automate the process of listing the branches from **various git repos**.

```
git ls-remote https://github.com/account/example.git
```

In case of **public repo**, its working fine. But if it is a **private repo**, then it is stuck asking for **creds**. I need to avoid this. It should **exit automatically** when **git asks for creds**. How can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you need to supply a username and password to authenticate with.  To avoid being prompted, you can do this by supplying them in the URL.

If Git is prompted for a username and password by the server (in this case via HTTP 401), then it will expect you to supply a username and password.  Generally, it will prompt you for a username and password:

```
% git ls-remote https://github.com/ethomson/secret
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

However, if you supply incorrect credentials, then Git will not prompt you.  It will instead try to use those credentials and - of course - fail.

You can specify the credentials in the URL by adding `username:password@` *before* the hostname:

```
% git ls-remote https://nobody:nopass@github.com/ethomson/secret
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://nobody:nopass@github.com/ethomson/secret/'
```

Comment: Yes, I did exactly this. I gave incorrect credentials. May be just an workaround.

Comment: I find it curious that if you give the incorrect credentials, you can still list a public repository.  However, it seems that you can do so.

Comment: IIRC, they're never sent.  You're only giving them to curl _in case_ you get a 401, and they'll be delivered in that case.  (It wouldn't deliver them to GitHub until you get an auth challenge because it doesn't know what auth mechanism to use.)